# Android PDFRenderer not rendering annotations on PDF

Tags: android, pdf

I have a PDF with ink annotations that I want to render, but the ink annotations does not show, only the pdf without the annotations.
If I use a lib to open the pdf I can see the PDF with its annotations.
I would like to show a thumbnail of the pdf's first page in a list view and therefore the need to render the pdf to bitmap.

Is there anyone else that have this issue or that can render pdf's with the annotations on them using PDFRenderer?

Comment: Hi @Hendri Have you found the solution? If yes, please share it. Thanks.